# Best approach to remove all parts of data column that don't match any part of a list?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, replace

I've got a dataframe with a column of song titles, label info and other messy string data.  I also have an isolated vector of specific song titles.  I'd like to filter out all characters that aren't a matched song from the song titles.  I'm using something like this, but is showing errors.

```
song.list <- c("Song.1","Song.2", "Song.3")
Mydata$Songs <- My data column containing all sorts of things including the songs I'm after

 levels(Mydata$Songs)[(Mydata$Songs) %in% song.list] <- "" #I'd like the opposite of this
 levels(Mydata$Songs)![(Mydata$Songs) %in% song.list] <- ""#My use of '!' doesn't work
```

I know that using the above indexing without the ! will work to replace my song list with blank space, but I'm trying to replace everything else with a blank space.  I've got about 29 songs in my list and about 1000 rows of messy string data in a single column. I've also tried gsub and grep to no avail.

Comment: You're putting the `!` in the wrong place! `[!(Mydata$Songs) %in% song.list]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to come up with a vectorized solution, but if I understood you correctly this loop over the factor levels should do the job:

```
library(stringr)

for (level in levels(df$A)) {
  match <- na.omit(str_extract(level, song.list))
  if (length(match) > 0) {
    levels(df$A)[levels(df$A) == level] <- match
  }
}
```

**Original answer which didn't do what the OP intended**

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do, but I think this is what you're after. This doesn't remove the rows, though!

```
levels(Mydata$Songs)[!Mydata$Songs %in% song.list] <- ""
```

Comment: Hi Oriol, thanks for this.  This is close to what I'm trying to do, but I'd like to filter out the parts of the string that don't match with song list.  Basically, I'm trying to pull the songs out of the jumbled string column.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the content of a few rows of `Mydata$Songs`? With that info I should be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Oriol, this is an example of what the first row of the data column comprise:

[1] Walkin' Blues (as R. Johnson)\n                                                                        \n                                        \n                    Raw Hide - \n                \n                        Assorted Studio Recordings 1987-1991 ‎(CDr, Comp, Ltd)


I'd like to pull out songs like "Walkin Blues".  Each row contains a different song and other string data.

Comment: I added a new attempt to solve this to my answer. Let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Hi Oriol, Thanks this seems to work great.  I was trying to do something similar but I was nowhere close, a all.  Thanks for your help; I've added a 'check' for your answer.